# Show progress bar in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, progress-bar

How can I show process bar if I Click The Download Button? I'd like show the Percentage Of Process Bar in Data Grid View Using WPF. How can I do it?

Comment: This is pretty unclear, please, try to clarify your question using [Edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/11215370) button

Comment: follow this link http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/misc-controls/the-progressbar-control/

Answer (score 0):

ProgressBar works by setting a minimum and maximum value and then incrementing a value, which will give a visual indication on how far in the process you currently are. See [this](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/misc-controls/the-progressbar-control/) tutorial with example.

Comment: I know About That Thing .But I want Like U Torrents